# Show page scroll only in fullscreen mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have following JS which used to make a page fullscreen after clicking on link:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleFullScreen()"></a>
```

```js
// mozfullscreenerror event handler
function errorHandler() {
   alert('mozfullscreenerror');
}
document.documentElement.addEventListener('mozfullscreenerror', errorHandler, false);

// toggle full screen
function toggleFullScreen() {
  if (!document.fullscreenElement &&    // alternative standard method
      !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement) {  // current working methods
    if (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
      document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
    }
  } else {
    if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
      document.cancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
      document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
      document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
    }
  }
}

// keydown event handler
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 70) { // F or Enter key
    toggleFullScreen();
  }
}, false);
```

Is there a way to make page scroll (overflow) be visible only in fullscreen mode, and when user cancel full screen by clicking same link again or by another way, overflow becomes hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use a class to represent "no overflow" or vice versa. And then just work it into your function, like so:

```
if (!document.fullscreenElement && !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement) {  // current working methods
        document.body.className = document.body.className.replace(' no-scroll', '');
        ...
} else {
    document.body.className += " no-scroll";
```

#### See [this working example](https://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/jowpz91s/) using the following method for "toggling" the class to turn scroll "on/off"

```
// add/remove no scroll class to body
function toggleNoScroll(off) {
    //  test if already exist:
    var a = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(document.body.classList, 'no-scroll') + 1;
    //  remove if does exist, so as not to double up
    document.body.className = document.body.className.replace(' no-scroll', '');
    //  add only if off IS False OR off is empty & it did not previously exist (thus "toggle")
    if (off === false || (off !== true && !a)) document.body.className += " no-scroll";
    return document.body.classList;
}
```

So then I have:

```
if (!document.fullscreenElement && !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement) {
    toggleNoScroll(true);
...
else {
    toggleNoScroll(false);
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Exept one thing. On test site you gave a link to everything is fine, but on my site the initial state of page is with overflow active, then when we use fullscreen and coming back to normal mode overflow becoming hidden as it supposed to be from the start. I mean when we just open the page overflow is there, but it shouldn`t be. Until we not use on/off link, then everything is working.

Comment: Already have found a solution, just deleted // run once toggleNoScroll(); Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to your body element when you run the `toggleFullscreen()` function like this:

`document.body.className += ' ' + 'fullScreened'`

then add a css rule like this:

`.fullScreened {
overflow:hidden;
}`

Let me know if it works :)

Comment: Forgive me my noobish questions, I am complete zero in JS. I have unique body class on my page: page-id-3929. So where exactly I need to paste your JS code? CSS I already know how to use, but not JS. That JS code I have posted above is in file and I have plugged this file to my page. Would be great if you can give me full code snippet which I should just copy-paste. Thanks for a help